# how to scroll UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I'm a beginner in iOS programming. I have a UITableView with 30 rows but simulator  only shows first 10 rows. So I want this tableview can scroll. Please help me.
Thanks so much.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, post your code so that we can help you see what may be wrong.

Comment: Dragging the cell won't work?

Comment: Some code please? It could be possible that you didn't configure enough cells for the tableview.

Comment: check if the user interaction is disabled. If disabled, enable it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're asking about how to scroll UITableView programmatically. You could try this method:

```
 - (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You should take a look at [UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard then make check mark in scrolling enabled option otherwise use this method:

```
 - (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```